# Effects of Higher Gravity & Thinner Atmosphere - Geography

Tags: gravity, atmosphere

Third question, I was told to separate these... How might this type of world effect the geography (land masses, water levels and what not)

Related questions:

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31327/effects-of-higher-gravity-thinner-atmosphere-inanimate-life-forms

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31325/effects-of-higher-gravity-and-thinner-atmosphere-animate-life-forms

Comment: IMO, this series of questions is VERY broad, and needs a lot more detail. How much higher gravity, relative to what? How much thinner Atmosphere, relative to what? Same atmospheric composition as ___, or a different composition? All these factors will affect the end result answer.

Comment: You should probably put some separation between these questions, lest someone brings up a point in one that you'd have to compensate for in all the others. It also makes things a bit less . . . confusing.

Comment: I can't be more precise if I don't have more data. Is your planet similar to any exoplanet, like Kepler 62 e/f ? If you write it I may be able to give you some more details.

Comment: I agree with HDE above. Splitting the questions is often a good idea. But it's best to spread them in time. Comments on a first question may change how you approach the next one.

Comment: user325655, welcome to Worldbuilding!  You've asked three related questions, all of which are currently on hold as too broad.  You can [edit] your questions by clicking on the "edit" link under them, and after you edit people will review to see if they can be reopened.  We want you to get good answers, but we need you to narrow the problem some -- "what would be the effects of this broad concept?" isn't really answerable.  *How much* higher gravity, thinner atmosphere, etc?  What are the other properties of your world?  Is it like earth otherwise, or quite different?  Thanks.

Comment: In addition to what has been mentioned above, even if questions are separate but related, **each question should be able to stand on its own.** This question doesn't currently stand on its own; there is not enough information in it to provide an answer. That makes it not just "too broad" but also almost certainly "unclear what you are asking".

Answer (score 2):

Higher gravity means lesser heights and depths, so the world is flatter, seas are shallower.  Higher gravity increases the rate at which the atmosphere thins out with height, so a higher elevation (achieved gradually) within a thin atmosphere might stand above the biologically effective atmosphere.  Maps might include land, water, and airless (relatively) areas.  Water evaporates quickly in thinner atmospheres, so shallow seas might evaporate entirely in dry seasons (like Australia's seasonal inland lakes.)  Maps might have great seasonal variations.

Comment: One other effect in thin atmospheres (building on Eithne's comment below) is that wind velocity tends to be higher (as observed on Mars).  In order to balance thermal differences the atmosphere has to move faster to carry enough energy to come to balance, and there is less mass to inertially resist the higher wind velocities.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add that the temperature could change a lot between day and night 'cos less atmosphere would distribute less well the heat. Including the effects of a higher gravity this would reduce a lot the habitable places, maybe (depending on the air) only in flatlands or valleys on relatively warm zones. Also, less atmosphere could not protect the ground level from radiations as the Earth's atmosphere does, so life would be reached by greater levels of radiation. If the planet doesn't have a strong magnetic field humans may have problems.

So, summing up, less atmosphere and more gravity= greater thermic imbalance, less habitable places (in certain conditions of no-so-perfect position in the habitable zone), more radiations.

I hope this answer is useful.